# Vue: filter an array of objects doesn't work properly

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make my list to be filtered by its author.

code below:

```js
    new Vue({
         el: '#board',
         data: {
            list: [],
            author: 'John'
         },
         mounted: function () {
             axios.get('data_url').then(response => { this.list = response.data; }).catch(error =>{console.log(error)});
         },
         methods: {
             filterbyauthor: function() {
                var newlist = this.list.filter(item => { item.author.trim() == this.author;});
                this.list = newlist;
              }
         }
    });
```

```
<button @click="filterbyauthor"></button>
```

I've tried everything I can but when I click the button it returns an array of zero-length. Please help me to find what my problem is.

Comment: Can you provide a small fiddle/demo?

Comment: You missed opening `{` in filter func and `return` statement.
Or you should delete closing `;}`

Comment: @AsiPle Wait. Finally! Everything works fine after deleting semi-colon. Why is that happening? I thought I should have to put semi-colon by end of the line.

Comment: You shouldn't put the semicolon at the end of line in this case. If you had this: `item => { return item.author.trim() === this.author; }` then it would've been valid, but you're using a shorthand: `item => item.author.trim() === this.author` more: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion/